# Cleaner code to swap multiple attributes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have images inside a div. I want them to change their sources with the click of a button. Right now I have this, which is working fine:

```
var isSwapped = false

$('.swapbutton').click(function swap(){
    if (isSwapped == false){
      $('.img1').attr('src','img11.png');
      $('.img2').attr('src','img22.png');
      etc.etc.
      isSwapped = true
    }
    else{
      $('.img1').attr('src','img1.png');
      $('.img2').attr('src','img2.png');
      etc.etc.
      isSwapped = false
    }
});
```

Is there a cleaner/neater code to use when I have a lot of images, so that I don't have to define every single source change?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Use three arrays: one for <img> ids, another for the first PNG filename set, and a third one for the other PNG set. Then use loops for changing the src attributes.

Comment: @kol: One loop, to be precise :-)

Comment: Thanks man, it took a while to figure the loops out, but works as it should! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming images in the form of:
    `html
    <img src="img1.png" data-alternate-src="img2.png" />`

You could use:

```
 $('.swapButton').click(function swap(){
      $('img').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                   newSrc = $this.attr('data-alternate-src');

            $this.attr('data-alternate-src', $this.attr('src'));
            $this.attr('src', newSrc);
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, I've managed to do it with arrays based on the suggestion kol made in his comment. I wanted to keep original filenames.

Comment: After reading it for the second time, it's an even more elegant approach. Since the other suggestion is in the form of a comment, I'll set your answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$('img').each(function(i,v){
    $(this).attr('src','img'+i+i);//for second case just use 'img'+i;
});
```